# Some data loss when using explode in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, explode

I want to parse some data (game names) from an external page :
https://www.mol.com/Product/GamesHive

using this code :

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://www.mol.com/Product/GamesHive';
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $first_step = explode('<div class="col-xs-4">', $content);
    $second_step = explode('</div>', $first_step[1]);
    echo $second_step[0];
?>
```

However some data is lost. The original page has `384` items and my page only has `169` items. What's the problem?

Comment: Because some elements might contain additional `class` or `id`

Comment: the problem is when `</div>` or `<div class="col-xs-4">` found that willbe removed.

Comment: Don't use string operations like this on html. Not all of the "col-xs-4" tags look like that, e.g. `<div class="col-xs-4 xs-margin-bottom-40">` will get MISSED by your explode. Use a DOM parser and xpath to get whatever you want.

Comment: i think there is relation between the result and the user country !

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl,
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL              => 'https://www.mol.com/Product/GamesHive',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER   => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST   => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER   => FALSE
    )
);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$arr = simplexml_import_dom(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($response))
         ->xpath('//div[@class="caption"]');

foreach ($arr as $val)
{
    echo $val->h5->a . '<br />';   
}

?>
```

Comment: Could you open up the code a bit more please? Atleast some comments would be nice. Also `VERIFYPEER/VERIFYHOST => false` is deemed bad practice.